# Question on benign and catastrophic cancellations

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point, rounding-error, machine-precision

I am studying theorem 4 in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) article (its proof is under theorem 13). From what I have learned, the theorem is helpful when $x$ is small but $1 \oplus x \neq 1$. 
At the end of theorem 4, it discussed idea of benign cancellation as follow:

> The results of this section can be summarized by saying that a guard digit guarantees accuracy when nearby precisely known quantities are subtracted (benign cancellation). Sometimes a formula that gives inaccurate results can be rewritten to have much higher numerical accuracy by using benign cancellation; however, the procedure only works if subtraction is performed using a guard digit. The price of a guard digit is not high, because it merely requires making the adder one bit wider. For a 54 bit double precision adder, the additional cost is less than 2%. For this price, you gain the ability to run many algorithms such as formula (6) for computing the area of a triangle and the expression $\ln(1 + x)$. Although most modern computers have a guard digit, there are a few (such as Cray systems) that do not.

From what I understood, the enhanced formula,$\frac{ln(x+1)}{(1+x)-1}$, helps replacing the catastrophic cancellation with benign cancellation. I assumed $\ln(1+x)$ causes catastrophic cancellation.

My Question: I cannot follow how the catastrophic cancellation was replaced with benign cancellation when we replaced  $\frac{ln(x+1)}{x}$ with $\frac{ln(x+1)}{(1+x)-1}$.

Can anyone please help clarifying this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you have a function that satisfies $f(1+x)=x\,g(x)$ with $g(0)=1\ne0$.

However, in computing $1⊕x$ you may lose precision in $x$ as $\bar x=(1⊕x)⊖1$ will be different by about $\mu=2^{-53}$ in `double` floating point. This means that the relative error between $x$ and $\bar x$ is $\mu/|x|$ can be arbitrarily high, and thus also the relative error between $f(1+x)$ and $f(1+\bar x)=f(1⊕x)$, seeing that
$$
f(1⊕x) = \bar x\,g(\bar x)
$$
will also exhibit this reduced precision. But one can easily repair most of the damage by dividing out $\bar x$ and multiplying with $x$ as the relative error between $x\,g(\bar x)$ and $x\,g(x)$ has the size $\mu g'(0)/g(0)$, that is, it is small independent of $x$ (for small $x$).

So finally, $\dfrac{x\,f(1+\bar x)}{\bar x}$ is implemented as

```
(x*f(1+x)) / ((1+x)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have a few questions: (1) I assumed $f(1+x) = \ln(1+x)$ and $g(x) = \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$. I thought g(0) is not defined here, but you wrote  g(0)= 1. Did I miss something?

Comment: (2) You wrote we lose precision in $x \oplus 1$.(I also saw it in the documentation for function log1p[1]). Assuming we have a small number,  (e.g. $2*10^{-14}, 3*10^{-14}$), which still satisfies  $x \oplus 1$ in a double precision machine. I don't see how I lose precision by adding 1 to it. I wrote it  on paper and I also enter in MATLAB, It can add them up accurately in double precision IEEE standards for floating point number. [1] http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log1p.html

Comment: The example is too simple. Say you have 4 decimal digits precision and $x=1.234\cdot 10^{-3}$, then $1+x=1.001234$ and $1⊕x=1.001$, thus losing 3 digits in $\bar x=1.000\cdot 10^{-3}$.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking too many questions.  The problem is in practice I see the inaccuracy in computing $\ln(1+x)$ for small number, (e.g. $x= 2∗10^{−13}, 3∗10^{−13},  ...$), and  log1p function resolves the issue. but in double precision IEEE standards we don't lose significance when computing $1+2∗10^{−13}$. So how did this theorem helped in practice?

Comment: `(1+2e-13)-1` gives `2.000621890374532e-13` which is a rather large loss of precision, from 16 places to 4. The logarithm values confirm this, as `log(1+2e-13)=2.000621890374332e-13` while `log1p(2e-13)=1.9999999999998001e-13`.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. in your example the loss of precision happens when we subtract the $1$. But $x+1$ by itself does not cause loss of precision. I don't know what I missed here.

Comment: Yes, and only that counts. You lose the digits of $x$ in the evaluation of $1+x$, but of course that value is as exact as representable. The cancellation or loss of precision effect only occurs in the, for this example similar, evaluations of $(1+x)-1$ or $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will read the theorem and your response again.I did not know the effect of losing digit is just not about  representing the number accurately.The effect can show up in subsequent steps such as $log(1+x)$.